# Can't access chart on word document (Interop C#)

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I have been struggling with this problem for a time and i can't find what's the problem. I'm updating a word document programmatically with Interop. I need to change the data of an embed chart. This is my code:

```
Word.InlineShape objShape = aDoc.InlineShapes[2];           
Word.Chart objChart = objShape.Chart;
Excel.Workbook book = objChart.ChartData.Workbook;
Excel.Worksheet dataSheet = book.Worksheets["Hoja1"];
dataSheet.Cells[2, 6] = 40; //dummy data
dataSheet.Cells[2, 7] = 10; //dummy data
```

But i got an exception on the second line as follow:

> This member can be accessed only for a chart object

Thanks :)

Comment: What does `objShape.HasChart` return? What kind of embedded chart is this (exactly which steps were used to create it)? Which version of Office are we dealing with?

Comment: Thanks Cindy. 
After using objShape.HasChart i got an error (Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c') so i re-added my assembly of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and now the code is working.

Answer (score 0):

After using objShape.HasChart i got an error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'

so i re-added my assembly of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and now the code is working.